# Angular 7: ng-invalid vs :invalid

Tags: css, angular, validation

I'm developing an Angular app with the intent of deploying it on mobile and web browser. 
When styling the form to show invalid inputs, should I target the Angular "**ng-invalid**" class or HTML5 "**:invalid**" CSS pseudo-class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the :invalid pseudo-class! For instance,

```
input[type="date"]:invalid:not(.ng-pristine) {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Other useful [css classes](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControlStatus) for input validation

Comment: You can check its support on various platforms over here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

Comment: If you wan ta different styling applied on mobile devices specifically, you may use Media Queries on your CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @wentjun - any clue how to resolve my query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515500/spring-angular-unable-to-upload-same-file-twice